# Three functions, one template

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I'm trying to use these three views django index.html but just let me apply individually. Is there any way you can use all three at the same time?

This is my file urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'dApp.views.funcion'),
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'index.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout')                
)
```

This is my file views.py

```
def funcion(request):
    n = 'example'
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'n':n}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Er, no. How can one URL do both login and logout, let alone presenting the index as well?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make three urls, each url point to a method.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', 'dApp.views.funcion'),
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'index.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout')
```

)

Answer (score 0):

my understanding about your question is, you need to add login and log out in index.html 
when you run the "dApp.views.funcion".

first of all : you can't add urls in this format , you need to add some index.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'dApp.views.funcion'),
    url(r'^/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'index.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout')                
)
```

call "{% url 'login' %} and {% url 'logout' %} in template , this answer is  my understanding about your question.